# "git submodule init" to use worktree (?) of remote for clone

Tags: git, git-submodules

I built myself a virtual machine in which I checkout a git repository that's on my host system. The repository itself was cloned from another repository, which is on our local VCS server. The repository has a number of submodules which are specified by relative URLs, to keep the repository working with both `ssh` and `http` transports.

My goal is to clone my host system git repository, in order to use (local) commits that are not yet pushed to the remote VCS server, and in order to have local clone speed, instead of going through VPN layers to reach the VCS.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with the relative submodule URLs, because the virtual machine's git tries to clone them from my host system, in which those repositories do not exist. Is there any workaround, to make the virtual machine clone them from my machine aswell, using the worktree maybe?